# Best way to design a base type with hundreds of child types with different properties values

Tags: c#, oop, design-patterns

I have this scenario:

There is one base type say its a document. Then there are almost 100 types of documents with varying properties.

for example:

```
BaseDoc:
    PropA = null
    PropB =defXyz
    PropC = defCCC

Doc A: BaseDoc
    PropA = true
    PropB =Xyz
    PropC = CCC

Doc B:BaseDoc
    PropA = false
    PropB =Xyz1
    PropC = CCC1
```

Right now this is what I was doing for each document, create new class and then add its properties. But now I have 100s of documents and it looks very bad to create 100 classes for each document.

What is the best way to achieve this type of result.

I am using c# if it matters.

Comment: If they all have the same three properties then why not just have one `Document` class and set those values on each instance?  It's not really clear to me what you're asking.

Comment: @David There are many properties and also there are different validations based on each document type. e.g if document type is Doc A do this, else if doc B then do that.

Comment: So is there anything actually common between them?

Comment: @John The properties are common but values for some documents might be common. real example is type= NationalID , it must have an expiry date, mandatory=true, etc So all documents have a type all documents have mandatory field but for some its true others its false

Comment: Are there properties with different types for different documents? I mean, can PropA be a bool in one document and an int in another?

Comment: It looks like you are mainly dealing with different instances of the same class. How many different document types do you have in "real-world"? If they all share some properties create a BaseDocument with those and then extend/override properties in derived classes (of BaseDocument). Different porperty *values* doesn't mean a different class.

Comment: @progmatico we have 90 real document types

Comment: @ZoharPeled No, They are always same types

Comment: So the only difference between two types of document is the values of the different properties and the validation rules?

Comment: @ZoharPeled yes

Comment: The problem with this question is that we have no way to dictate what you should do because you've only stated a fact.  Fact: you have many documents.  How one should designed a system to represent these documents is *completely dependent on* what you plan to do with them.  We don't know what you're doing with them, so there should be no valid answer yet.

Comment: okay, leaving the fact aside. Let me ask a question. In case you have hundreds of sub-classes what is a way to solve this issue. I dont feel this is correct to create 100 classes in this case. Is there a solution? Let's take another example of cars. Now base is car but cars can be of hundreds of sub-types with varying properties.

Comment: I disagree with your car example, while at the same time I think @ZoharPeled answer is reasonable. If you have to validate many different rules, there is no way to escape to writing code with those many rules. About the cars, different cars have a lot in common actually. Given a common base class Car or BaseCar, I don't think you'll have to subclass in the hundreds. That would mean the base class is not very useful.

Comment: But if I read your mind correctly, yes there is a valid reason for your doubts. Every time you think of writing many many variation of a class, it may make sense to transfer that knowledge into a text configuration file where you edit by hand and add new variations instead of coding classes. Then you define a single more abstract class capable of loading its instances with the required attributes from the configuration.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the comments to the question, if the document types differ only by the values of the properties and the validation rules, I would have a single class for all documents.
As for the validation, I would suggest creation a validator interface with a single method that takes in a document and returns a bool - and have different classes implement this interface for different document types:

```
public interface IDocumentValidator
{
    bool IsValid(Document document);
}


public class DocAValidator : IValidator
{
    public bool IsValid(Document document)
    {
        // specific implementation for doc A
    }
}

public class DocBValidator : IValidator
{
    public bool IsValid(Document document)
    {
        // specific implementation for doc B
    }
}
```

Of course, if you have parts of the validation that are common between different document types, you can create a base class to hold these parts and avoid code repetition:

```
public class CommonDocumentValidator : IValidator
{
    public virtual bool IsValid(Document document)
    {
        // common validation rules here
    }
}
```

and then inherit this class like this:

```
public class DocAValidator : CommonDocumentValidator
{
    public override bool IsValid(Document document)
    {
        if(!base.IsValid(document)) return false;

        // specific implementation for doc A
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks but in this case too I will have 100 document classes, this was actually the base problem I wanted to solve that I feel I will have to create too many classes

Comment: No, you have a single document class and an x number of validator classes, all implementing the same interface.

Comment: sorry, i understand i meant 100 (validation) classes

Comment: Yes, you would have as many validator classes as different validations. If you have 100 different document type and the validation for each document type is unique, you would have to write 100 different validations - Now the question is would it be better to write them all in a single class or have a class for each validation type - I would say the latter is better anyway you look at it.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need strongly typed access to properties I would use a dictionary of key value pairs of strings or objects if you need more flexibility. You can make them virtual so that inheriting classes can override all members or optionally add/remove from the Dictionary. If you want strongly typed access you can use the PropN class as your key. If you really have 90 **different** types of documents you may want to add the dictionary as a constructor argument. But if there are really many different types of documents there will be different behaviour across them and inheriting and overriding some of the defaults of the base document is probably the preferred approach.

```
public class BaseDoc
{

    protected virtual Dictionary<string, string> Props { get; } = new Dictionary<string, string>()
    {
        { "PropA", null },
        { "PropB", "defXyz" },
        { "PropC", "defCCC" }
    };

    protected virtual Dictionary<PropN, string> Props2 { get; } = new Dictionary<PropN, string>()
    {
        { PropN.PropA, null },
        { PropN.PropB, "defXyz" },
        { PropN.PropC, "defCCC" }
    };

    public IReadOnlyDictionary<string, string> PropsReadOnly => Props;

    public IReadOnlyDictionary<PropN, string> Props2ReadOnly => Props2;

}
public class PropN
{
    private PropN(string name) => Name = name;

    public string Name { get; }

    public static readonly PropN PropA = new PropN("PropA");
    public static readonly PropN PropB = new PropN("PropB");
    public static readonly PropN PropC = new PropN("PropC");
}
```